# In HP1 why did Harry only grab one letter when they were coming down the chimney?

Tags: harry-potter

Surely he would have caught five, at least, and hid them from Vernon while he was getting sprayed by the letters? Then he could have read any one?

Comment: If only he were a Ravenclaw, he would have picked up the damn letter from the ground.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, because Vernon didn’t give him a chance. In the book, he pulls Harry out of the room before he has a chance to grab a single letter, let alone several:

> Something came whizzing down the kitchen chimney as he spoke and caught him sharply on the back of the head. Next moment, thirty or forty letters came pelting out of the fireplace like bullets. The Dursleys ducked, but Harry leapt into the air trying to catch one – “Out! OUT!”
>
> **Uncle Vernon seized Harry around the waist and threw him into the hall.** When Aunt Petunia and Dudley had run out with their arms over their faces, Uncle Vernon slammed the door shut. They could hear the letters still streaming into the room, bouncing off the walls and floor.
>
> “That does it,” said Uncle Vernon, trying to speak calmly but pulling great tufts out of his moustache at the same time. “I want you all back here in five minutes, ready to leave. We’re going away. Just pack some clothes. No arguments!”
>
> — *Philosopher's Stone*, chapter 3 (*The Letters From No One*)

Perhaps Harry could have snuck one away while he was supposed to be packing, but Vernon would have seen it as he dragged Harry out of the room. Once they’re packed and leave Privet Drive, Uncle Vernon keeps such a close eye on Harry that he doesn’t have a chance to grab a letter and hide it until he can read it in privacy.

Comment: Damn... beat me by 3 minutes!!!! +1

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever seen those glass cases where someone stands inside and the turn a fan on and drop cash in and you have like 1 minute to grab as much cash as you can. Typically you don't get much cash out of it because paper on the wind is quite tricky to catch. 
 1. I assume Harry was in a similar situation with them blowing around the room. 
 2. or Harry grabbed 1 and ran (which he did) purely because he hoped they wouldn't notice if he only grabbed 1.

Comment: Yes that is true but it was blatently obvious harry would try and grab one when the dursleys and harry knew to well they were for him and they had been stopping them from having one! Yeah I have seen the glass cases heeheh good resemblance!!hehe! But surely he could sneek one down his pants or something and they'd be none the wiser?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually recall him catching *any* of them in the book - the Dursleys rather hastily moved him away from the letters so he wouldn't.

But in the movie, I recall him catching exactly one, then hastily running off to open it as quick as he could.

Clearly he was only interested in the contents of the letter, and only needed to open one to find out.  Snatching others would just slow him down, and with the Dursleys right there, they would've taken them away immediately.  Wheras snatching one to open up in a hurry was much faster.